# How to Specify pgfpages 2 on 1 Output for a Range of Pages Only

Tags: imakeidx, layout, makeindex, pgfpages, idxlayout

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

\begin{document}
\Large
\chapter{} 
\lipsum[1-4]\index{entry first chap.}
\chapter{} 
\lipsum[1-2]\index{entry second chap.}
\chapter{} 
\lipsum[3-4]\index{entry third chap.}

\idxlayout{columns=2}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

with its last two output pages:

[image]

[image]

Notice from the code that there should be three index entries; however, the output (for some reason) with `pgfpages` 2 on 1 output displays only two of them. I have encountered something similar before and posted this question: [Index Entries Disappear with the Use of pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616439/index-entries-disappear-with-the-use-of-pgfpagesuselayout2-on-1)

Alas, it attracted no answers.

So now I ask---

QUESTION: How I may specify the 2 on 1 output for a range of pages---in this case, for actual pages 1-6 only; and so a full page output for the 7th page containing, hopefully, the full index?

Comment: This is doable with pgfmorepages, 
which is an enhancement of pgfpages. See the package details on ctan   https://ctan.org/pkg/pgfmorepages or on github https://github.com/loopspace/pgfmorepages

Comment: @Andrew Stacey Thank you for providing these links.