# Why is Pgfpages with the Pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1} Command Not Picking Up the Index?

Tags: indexing, printing, imakeidx, layout, pgfpages

The following code

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{idxlayout}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}

\begin{document}
\LARGE
Some words.\index{1st Index entry.}
Some more words.\index{2nd Index entry.}
And some more words.\index{3rd Index entry.}

\idxlayout{columns=1}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

produces the index

[image]

But when I run the code with the command `\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}`, this is what appears:

[image]

QUESTION: Does anyone know why `pgfpages` with the `\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}` command---which prints two output pages per page---is not picking up the Index? Thank you.

Comment: Interesting, reproducible with `imakeidx` package, but works well with `makeidx` package. Also looks like a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/616439, a question asked by OP in 2021.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Sorry but the linked question has no answer nor comment, except for one you just added.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ You are right. I modified the title of the linked answer to attract more attention. Feel free to vote for reopening if you disagree. I may misunderstood your first comment.